# "Crítico aberto" significa alguma coisa?

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

Por exemplo

> Pedro é um crítico aberto do casamento do João com a Maria.

Sem mais nenhum contexto para ajudar, o que é que entenderiam por esta frase?

O que eu pretendo dizer é que o Pedro não se preocupa em esconder as suas críticas nem mesmo do João e da Maria. Em inglês poderíamos dizes "open critic." Isto é uma maneira aceitável de exprimir a ideia? Há outra maneira melhor de exprimir a ideia com *Pedro* + um único adjetivo?

*Crítico declarado* é demasiado forte. Não quero dizer que o Pedro tenha montado uma campanha, ou ande obcecado.

Comment: http://www.sinonimos.com.br/aberto/ vê se ajuda.

Comment: Eu sou um consulente regular desse site, e o significado 8, legitima alguma coisa o meu uso de _aberto_ acima. Mas nestas coisas os dicionários são por vezes limitados, e não substituem a sensibilidade do ouvido das pessoas reais.

Comment: Eu sei Jacinto, mas não estou a conseguir pensar em nada.

Comment: Que tal  Pedro é crítico _manifesto_ do casamento? Ou então alterar a frase para Pedro critica _abertamente_ o casamento?

Comment: É um possibilidade. O dicionário de sinónimos sugerido pelo @JorgeB. indica _público_ e _notório_ como sinónimos de _manifesto_. Estou também a pensar em coisas na linha de _indissimulado_. O google só encontra 715 ocorrências!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Crítico aberto" significa apenas que o sujeito mostra o seu desagrado publicamente. Neste caso *aberto* tem o mesmo valor que *público*.

Comment: É verdade. E _público_ até me parece melhor que aberto.